# Google Sheets - ImportXML Not Updating After DOM Change

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently coding a game and I'm attempting to get the uploaded high scores of users into Google Sheets, but ImportXML only loads the initial empty list items.

Google Sheet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVbqT.jpg)

```css
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("index.html","//li"),1) -> Result = #N/A
```

HTML

```html
        <ul id="list">
            <li></li> <!-- Name -->
            <li></li> <!-- Score -->
            <li></li> <!-- Email -->
        </ul>
```

JS

```js
let dataArray = [dataName, dataScore, dataEmail];
        let list = document.querySelectorAll("li");

//        for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
//            // Create the list item:
//            var item = document.querySelector("li");
//            var listText = document.createTextNode(dataArray[i]);
//            item.appendChild(listText);
//            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(item);
//            console.log( $( "li" )[ i ] );
//        }
        
        //Add items to the list
        for(let i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
        list[i].innerHTML = dataArray[i];
        }
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML only is able to access the source code of the file, not the modified DOM.